# how to bind gridview values to textbox on click of edit button in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

on click of edit button in gird view unable to bind the label value in template field to 
the text box on same page on row data bound event

```
TxtVendor.Text = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblGridvendname"), Label).Text
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are having?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question a bit? what error are you getting? did you debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work for me.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lblVendor = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblGridvendname");
                TextBox txtVendor = new TextBox();
                txtVendor.Text = lblVendor.Text.ToString();
            }
```